# 3rd order non homgenuous ODE particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The formula is $y'''+4y'=3x-1$

characteristic polynomial= $r^3+4r=0$

complementary solution is: $y_c = C_1cos(2x)+C_2sin(2x)$

Since $3x-1$ is a polynomial

$y_p=Ax+B$ since there is no duplication with the complimentary solution this is the correct form

$y'_p=A$

$y'''_p=0$

So we have $0 + 4A = 3x-1$

which means $A=-\frac{1}{4}$

which means the particular solution is $-\frac{1}{4}x$

But somehow the book says the answer is $\frac{1}{8}(3x^2-2x)$

I dont understand at all how it could be $\frac{1}{8}(3x^2-2x)$ It makes no sense

Comment: There is a flaw in the step where you obtain value of A. You cannot get that value as there is a 3x term on right hand side.

Comment: I dont follow. They did an example just like this in the opening of the chapter so I tried to follow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $y_p(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$. Then $y_p'''=0$ and you obtain $4y_p'=8Ax+4B=3x-1$. Therefore, $8A=3\implies A=3/8$ and $4B=-1\implies B=-1/4$.

So then you might wonder about the $C$. Well in your homogeneous solution, you missed it. When you solve $r^3+4r=r(r^2+4)=0$, one of th solutions is $r=0$. Hence, a constant gets added to the homogeneous solution.

When you write the general solution, the constant gets absorbed.

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense then. I totally just missed that. Great explanation

Answer (score 1):

$$y'''+4y'=3x-1, y=y_g+y_p ~~~(1)$$
First solve the homogeneous part $$y'''+4y'=0~~~(2)$$
Let $y=e^m{x}$ in (2), we get $m^3+4m=0 \implies m=0, \pm 2i$, then
$$y_g(x)=C_1+C_2 \sin 2x +C_3 \cos 2x~~~(3)$$
Let $y_p(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$ in (1), then
$$6A+4(3Ax^2+2Bx+C)=3x-1~~~~(4)$$ Comparing co-efficiets of various powers in (3), we get $A=0, B=3/8, C=1/4$
So the total solution of (1) is
$$y=C_1+C_2\sin 2x +C_3 \cos 2x+3x^2/8-x/4+D$$
$C_1+D=C'_1$. Finally,
$$y=C'_1+C_2 \sin 2x +C_3 \cos 2x+3x^2/8-x/4$$

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of equation where you have  only derivatives  on LHS:
$$y'''+4y'=3x-1$$
It's better to choose:
$$y'_p=Ax+B$$
$$\implies y'''_p=0$$
So we have 
$$4(Ax+B)=3x-1 \implies A=\dfrac 3 4, B=-\dfrac 1 4$$
Therefore:
$$y'_p=\dfrac 3 4 x-\dfrac 14$$
$$y_p=\dfrac 3 8 x^2-\dfrac  14x+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it is correct to equate a non constant polynomial and a constant?

As you have degree 1 polynomial on right hand side of differential equation, choose a degree 2 polynomial as candidate of particular solution, so that it's derivative is of degree 1 and we can thus obtain it's coefficients.